# Rebasing a web view does not give me the latest versions of some files

Tags: clearcase

A colleague of mine checked in updates to several files, some new files and the
renaming of two files, delivered and made a new baseline. When I rebase my view
to the latest baseline I can see the new versions as well as the delivery in
the version trees, but the "view selected version" is not the latest version.

We both use web views and ClearCase UCM with the Eclipse plugin for Linux.

I cannot find out how this could have happened. There are no locks on the files
and they aren't chacked out. How does `ClearCase` determine that my view should
not use the latest version of a file?

[image: CCRC]

Answer (score 0):

Web view means CCRC.

> How does ClearCase determine that my view should not use the latest version of a file?

It is based on the config spec of your web view, and that config spec isn't always in sync with the configuration (ie list of baseline).

See "[Synchronize a CCRC view with a shared UCM stream](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21246264)", and check if "Update Resource" can fix your situation.

[image]

Comment: I only use the Eclipse plugin. [This](http://i.imgur.com/KnyVu.png) is how it looks for me. I have tried all, but they all report that everything is ok. Sorry for the vague answer; my knowledge is limited.

Comment: @Øsse in that case, is your view attached to the Stream, or is it a base view, for which you specify the config spec yourself? The easiest way to know what is going on is to ask to a ClearCase admin for the config spec of your web view (he/she has access to your view on the CCRC server and can do a `cleartool catcs` in your view)